# Download pdf in bulk on click of Download button

Tags: zoho-deluge, deluge

I have parent record in that records have subform on subform are attacheched with 5 file and i want downld all file on one clickof download action button on same time so i want how to code ?

In deluge script individual pdf will be downloaded but all files in bulk which is attached are not downloading same time on one click of download button.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example Deluge script that you can use to download all attachments from a subform on a Zoho Creator record:

```
openUrl("https://creator.zoho.in/file" + zoho.appuri + "<subform_report_name>/" + <record_id> "/<File_upload_field_name>/download?filepath=/" + <File_upload_field_name>,"popup window");
```

Example code

```
for each  Document in input.Documents 
{
  openUrl("https://creator.zoho.in/file" + zoho.appuri + "All_Test_Documents/" + Document.ID + "/File_upload/download?filepath=/" + Document.File_upload,"popup window");
}
```